# How to update value object into array in MongoDB Golang?

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to update my addresses into my person data:

```
if _, ok := update["addressName"]; ok {
  request = bson.M{"addresses": bson.M{"addressName": update["addressName"]}}
} else {
  request = update
}
_, err = people.UpdateOne(context.TODO(), filter, bson.M{"$set": request})
```

this doesn't create an object in the array,

I want to have a result like this:

```
{
 "updateAt": TIME_NOW
 "addresses": [
    {"addressName": "ONLY", default: true},
    {"addressName": "ONLY", default: true}
 ]
}
```

how is the correct way to request for an object in array with **MongoDB Driver**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are `$set`ting the `addresses` to an array containing a single element. Either you have to set the `addresses` to an array containing all the elements you need, or you have to add to that array using `$push`:

```
_, err = people.UpdateOne(context.TODO(), filter, bson.M{"$push":bson.M{"addresses":bson.M{ address info }})
```

Comment: I follow that but not work: here is the request `request = bson.M{"$push":bson.M{"addresses":bson.M{ "addressName": update["addressName"] }}}`

Comment: the address was null and then I update like your answer, it doesn't change, but after I $set array of data of it and then run your code , it was work, so is that mean we can't do like your syntax if that addresses in mongo null ?

Comment: I just tried as you said and it works. What version of mongodb are you using?

Comment: Is it null, or does it not exist? If it is null, it'll fail.

Comment: MongoDB shell version v4.2.7, mongo-driver 1.3.4, did you create person data ? and make on addresses null `not empty array` ? and then run your code? I was like that and nothing happen

Comment: If address is null, $push will fail. Use $set with data containing all the elements in the array then.

Comment: it exist but it was null on addresses after I create the person data, and then run your code, and nothing change , well yes it was empty , `internal system error`

Comment: If possible, do not create the `addresses` field if it is null. If you're using son tags, add `omitempty` so it is not inserted as null. If it doesn't exist or if it is empty array, $push will work.

Comment: how to I change one address  in `addresses` file then ? let say I want to change `addressName: ONE` to be default: false

Comment: That would be using  a query containing `$elemMatch` to find the address element with `addressName: ONE`, and then update with `addresses.$.default`

Comment: with bson.M or what?

Comment: query: bson.M{"addresses":bson.M{"$elemMatch":bson.M{"addressName":"ONE"}}}, Update: bson.M{"$set":bson.M{"addresses.$.default":false}}

Comment: I got it thanks, oh ya, do u know how to set default value in each field as well? I have not found any resource about this, can I use jsonSchema during create collection??

Comment: I don't know. There should be documentation around json schema use. I suggest you try and see.